# How to illustrate large data using bar plot or other styles?

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization

I have a set of data and want to plot them. However I don't know how to plot them nicely. I tried to use bar plot in Matlab and the resulted plot is not readable. 
I thought to ask if there is a setting or even a new style to plot my results in a better way.
There are 15 bars for each element of x axis [1:19]. 
Here you can see the required data:

```
DAT=...
[2.476  4.142   0.000   4.302   4.302   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
6.680   8.703   2.611   6.680   6.680   3.261   0.000   3.799   6.680   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
7.672   6.498   7.809   7.809   7.809   6.615   5.062   7.809   7.809   3.916   5.895   7.809   2.780   5.195   2.385
27.126  17.441  11.386  0.000   0.000   17.435  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
0.085   0.156   0.284   0.284   0.284   0.000   0.284   0.284   0.284   0.226   0.284   0.284   0.284   0.284   0.284
10.688  12.159  10.688  10.688  10.688  10.688  10.073  5.633   10.688  0.000   0.000   6.681   0.000   0.000   0.000
11.002  11.020  11.002  11.002  11.002  11.002  11.002  9.456   11.002  5.459   2.434   3.585   3.527   2.160   0.117
2.111   2.111   2.111   2.111   2.111   2.111   2.111   0.000   0.000   2.111   2.111   0.000   0.000   0.581   0.000
9.085   9.906   9.085   1.256   9.085   9.085   9.085   7.299   0.000   9.085   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
3.661   3.661   3.661   3.661   3.661   3.661   3.661   0.000   0.000   1.206   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
3.307   3.703   3.307   2.968   3.307   3.307   3.307   0.000   0.000   3.307   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
4.136   4.123   4.123   4.123   4.123   4.123   4.123   4.123   0.000   4.123   4.123   0.000   3.350   0.000   0.000
2.993   3.000   2.993   2.993   2.993   2.993   0.000   1.134   0.000   2.993   0.000   0.000   1.938   0.000   0.000
1.857   1.864   1.857   1.857   1.857   1.857   1.857   1.857   0.000   1.857   1.857   0.016   1.857   0.704   0.000
3.754   3.754   3.754   3.754   3.754   3.754   3.754   0.000   0.000   3.754   3.754   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2.752   2.760   2.752   2.752   2.752   2.752   2.752   2.752   0.000   2.752   2.752   2.752   2.752   2.752   0.000
3.788   5.611   3.788   3.788   3.788   3.788   3.788   3.369   0.000   3.788   3.788   0.000   3.788   0.000   0.000
0.132   0.123   0.123   0.123   0.132   0.123   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
15.465  14.081  12.468  4.808   1.787   12.858  11.067  3.644   9.317   11.846  10.631  4.233   8.394   5.094   4.225];
bar(DAT)
```

[image]

Comment: You could plot it as a heatmap using something like `imshow` or `imagesc`. You might want to scale your data first though e.g. `DAT = 255*DATA/max(DAT(:))`

Comment: Thanks for checking my question. There are 19 Generators that produce Power. The vertical axis shows the generated active power and X axis shows the generators index(1,2,...,19). There are 15 cases that are included in the plot using different bars. @Matt

Comment: What aspect of information do you want to emphasize/compare/show? Is it important that all the values are visible?

Comment: Well I want to show how much each generator(1,..,19) has produced for every case (15 cases). So it seems I want to illustrate all information. @Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out `bar3(DAT)`

Output graph:

[image]

Comment: hmm it looks much better. I check it. @jucestain